# Why don't links work when I use :before / :after background URLs?

Tags: html, css, opacity, pseudo-element

I 'd like add a little background structure to my css buttons. That's what the button code looks like:

```
.button a {
color: white;
padding: 2% 6%;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 3%;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
background-color: #49c0f0; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#49c0f0), to(#2CAFE3));
position:relative;}
```

Now I user :after to add an almost transparent background image to the button:

```
.button a:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:url(../images/structure.png);
opacity:0.05;}
```

It looks pretty nice but unfortunately all of the links before and after those buttons are not clickable anymore. I was wondering if it has something to do with the absolute / relative positioning of the surrounding items...

Comment: Please create a snippet on here with the relevant html code for us to more easily find the problem.  It should recreate the exact issue you are having.

Comment: FYI, you can have multiple background images on a single element, so you can both have the gradient and your image without using the `:after` http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 1):

That's because `.button a:after` is absolutely positioned, so by default it is displayed in front of `.button a`.

To avoid that, you can use [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index):

```css
.button a:after {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for z-index :-) "-1" didn't work so I tested "0" and it worked! I don't exactly know why but...